# Javascript: is safe to delete a function when called?

Tags: javascript

I want to permit to call `digest` method only once, so function is deleted when digest has been calculated and `that` is a simple object without functions.

```
var Content = function(filename) {
  var that = {};
  var name = path.basename(filename);

  var digest = function(callback) {
    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
      that.hash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(data).digest('hex');
      delete that.digest; // IS THIS SAFE?
      callback();
    });
  };

  that.digest = digest;
  that.name = name;

  return that;
};
```

Use it:

```
var content = Content('/path/to/file');
content.digest(function() {
  // content.hash is available
});
```

Is this safe and good practice?

Comment: possible is better use simple flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's safe because delete just removes that reference, it doesn't free any memory so your function is still there:

> Unlike what common beliefs suggests, the delete operator has nothing to do with directly freeing memory (it only does indirectly via breaking references.

Is it a good practice? Well this is just my opinion...I think it's not really clear when you read that code (you need to read it all to understand what happens) so I would avoid it in favor of something else (if you're using some kind of lazy initialization you may use another property, for example). That said with proper comments in code...